# I want to make slider with events to capture the value in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android

[I am looking for Xamarin Android version of this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECSqU.png)

Comment: Maybe Range Slider control for syncfusion can meet your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar

It is similar, but this will not exactly match your requirement.

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbarslider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="10"/>

 public class SeekBarActivity : SeekBar.IOnSeekBarChangeListener
    {
        public void OnProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, bool fromUser)
        {
        }

        public void OnStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
        }

        public void OnStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.seekbarlayout);

            var seekBar = FindViewById<SeekBar>(Resource.Id.seekbarslider);
            seekBar.SetOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seekbar i have tried but i want exactly same ui